# Read the content of the HTML link in a tweet

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I am working on a new app that will read data from twitter. I can read the tweets successfully, but if the tweet has a link, the app should read the content of that link (the content of the page on that link) and display it instead of the tweet content (like what happened in the FLIPBOARD APP).

Is there any class that do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in that will do auto previews for you, but you can always scan the tweet for links when received, then fire off some asynchronous NSURLConnections to fetch the website content, adding it to the tweet when done.